# Нужны ли знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли дополнительные знаки препинания?

Препарат принимать внутрь один раз в день ежедневно в одно и то же время натощак.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания нужны, так как информация зрительно плохо воспринимается.

После небольшого редактирования: **Препарат принимать внутрь  (в течение месяца):  один раз в день, натощак, в одно и то же время.**

Comment: А если нет возможности перестроить предложение, как бы вы расставили знаки?
Как считаете, так подойдет:
Препарат принимать внутрь один раз в день, ежедневно в одно и то же время натощак?

Comment: Здесь разные могут быть комбинации. Информация должна даваться удобно для чтения и   дозированно для восприятия: от более важной к уточняющей. Вот еще вариант:  Препарат принимать внутрь один раз в день натощак,  ежедневно, в одно и то же время.

Comment: Ваш второй вариант лучше. В том плане, что вся информация сохранилась.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение требует правки. Как минимум слово "ежедневно" здесь лишнее. А если ничего не менять, то задача поставить запятые **правильно** становится едва ли выполнимой. В качестве компромисса предлагаю слова  "ежедневно в одно и то же время" считать уточнением и выделить их запятыми:

**Препарат принимать внутрь один раз в день, ежедневно в одно и то же время, натощак.**

P.S. Вот что нашлось в сети (http://www.lsgeotar.ru/afinitor-1062.html)

*Препарат Афинитор® следует принимать внутрь один раз в день ежедневно в одно и то же время (предпочтительно утром) натощак или после приема небольшого количества пищи, не содержащей жира.*

Авторы предпочли обойтись без запятых. По-моему, результат выглядит плохо.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит отрывать слово "натащак". Лучше написать так.

Препарат принимать внутрь один раз в день натощак (ежедневно) и в одно и то же время.

P.S.Можно использовать вариант Арины ( в комментариях).

Comment: Благодарю за варианты. Но в этом случае попросили проверить только орфографию и пунктуацию, даже минимально не меняя структуру предложений. Я понимаю, что оно сложное для восприятия и корявое.